# Disable/reset bold in xterm

Tags: console, xterm, ansi-escape

With escape sequences `"\033[21m"` is used to reset/remove bold/bright:

```
echo -e "Text\033[1mMore text\033[21mEnd"
```

must return:

Text**More text**End

but I get

Text**More text**E̲n̲d̲

As you can see, in `xterm` `"\033[21m"` changes to underline and to reset bold we need to use `"\033[0m"`, why is this?

Is there a way to change this behavior? (maybe launching xterm with some parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *[XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m.1CA7)*, SGR 21 is "doubly-underlined":

```
CSI Pm m  Character Attributes (SGR).

        Ps = 2 1  -> Doubly-underlined (ISO 6429).
        Ps = 2 2  -> Normal (neither bold nor faint).
        Ps = 2 3  -> Not italicized (ISO 6429).
        Ps = 2 4  -> Not underlined.
        Ps = 2 5  -> Steady (not blinking).
        Ps = 2 7  -> Positive (not inverse).
        Ps = 2 8  -> Visible, i.e., not hidden (VT300).
        Ps = 2 9  -> Not crossed-out (ISO 6429).
```

Perhaps you intended SGR 22.

The doubly-underlined feature was implemented in xterm [patch #305](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_305):

> minor reorganization to implement “filler” SGR features. There are no established applications which rely upon these; some people find them amusing.
>
> separate bits used to manage drawing state from attribute-bits.
>
> implement SGR codes 2, 3, 9, 21 and their corresponding resets.
>
> add configure option `--disable-wide-attrs` to disable the feature.